# What is the usability of fields/ methods in an angular module?

Tags: angular

Is there any usability for  fields/ methods etc. of an angular module?
If so – when is it useful?

Comment: Start an Angular course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would usually find `forRoot/forChild` methods in modules, but other than that, not much.

What I personally like to do is make module-wide settings and configurations : for instance, with Angular Material, you can provide your own SVGs to be treated as icons. In that particular case, I like to provide my icons into the app module.

Another thing you can usually do in your modules is initiate your state management, and do all the boilerplate required for it (getting some static data on the server etc).

In the end, it's more about code location and your own personal preferences, but modules are not meant to hold code, they are here to package a feature that you want to reuse, and to organize your code.

Answer (score 0):

The most common usecase I see for methods in a module is returning a list of providers dedicated to that module.

You can find a lot of them in the angular code base.

For example in `BrowserModule`:

```
  static withServerTransition(params: {appId: string}): ModuleWithProviders<BrowserModule> {
return {
  ngModule: BrowserModule,
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_ID, useValue: params.appId},
  ],
};
```

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a5bd5ddbaace240610f0fef537ca759ab7241e35/packages/platform-browser/src/browser.ts#L250C1-L256C7)